# how to set a property of an object inside a NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have written a class which has a property, I want to add instances of this class into a mutable array and after that I want to set the num property of the instances. but I dont know the correct syntax. Please tell me the correct syntax or method to do this.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property int num;

-(void) method;
+(id) getClassAObj:(int)number;

@end
--------------------------------
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize num;

-(void) method{
    NSLog(@"ClassA method Called");
}
+(id) getClassAObj:(int)number {

    ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    obj.num = number;
    return obj;

}

@end
-----------------------
```

now in main I want to set the num property manually but I dont know what is the correct syntax

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [ClassA getClassAObj:9],
                                [ClassA getClassAObj:4], nil];
        NSLog(@"%i",[[array objectAtIndex:0] num]);
        NSLog(@"%i",[array[1] num]);
        //array[1].num = 3;              <--- Help needed here
        //[[array[1]]num 3];             <--- this is also not correct syntax

        NSLog(@"%i",[array[1] num]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know If I am wrong with the syntax or may be it is not possible to set a property of an object inside an array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ClassA *anObject = array[<index>];
[anObject setNum:<yourNumber>];
```

You can also use the `[<array> objectAtIndex:<index>]` method, but the above is the newer way to do it.

Good Luck!

EDIT:

If you want to validate the object (so it will not crash, but it will also not work as expected) your code can look like this:

```
id anObject = array[<index>];
if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"ClassA")]]) {
    [(ClassA *)anObject setNum:<number>];
}
```

If you want to validade the exact message (the setter in this case), you should check if the object responds to this selector. This is useful when you have objects of different classes, but they all respond to the message. It would look like this:

```
id anObject = array[<index>];
if ([anObject respondsToSelector:@selector(setNum:)) {
    [anObject setNum:<number>];
}
```

Comment: Your code will fail if for some reason the object at that index is not of type ClassA, you should do a validation to complete the answer ;)

Comment: Better to declare the object as id and check that the object responds to the setNum method before sending the message.

Comment: @danypata: If you're not expecting other classes in that array, there isn't anything much more appropriate that you could do if your validation failed than say, "Well, we've bugged out. Need to fix that." Which is already what it will do if you just send the wrong message anyway.

Comment: @danypata Thanks for the comments. I have added examples for validating the class or validating the actual message/selector.

Comment: The thing is it's always good to validate the objects from an array especially when you are doing a cast, not necessarily for checking the fail but for avoiding crashes.

Comment: @danypata I agree with you. However, depending on the actual situation, sometimes the code not doing anything is just as bad as crashing.

Answer (score 3):

```
array[1].num = 3;
```

This would work, however, the problem is, the compiler loses track of type information about an object if you put it in an array. The runtime still recognizes what kind of object it is. You just have to politely inform the compiler.

```
((ClassA *)(array[1])).num = 3;
```

Comment: Your code will fail if for some reason the object at that index is not of type ClassA, you should do a validation to complete the answer ;)